# Store object temporarily without using database

Tags: javascript

I am learning the Object in javascript. In the following code, whenever I click Spawn, a new player is immediately spawned. What I want to do is, when I click Spawn, **the player not immediately spawned** instead a button with their name on it is created. And then when I click that button, the player whose name in that button is spawned.

I know I can do this easily if I have the database of player but **what if this is just temporary, so there is no database.** How can I do that?

```js
function spawnPlayer() {
  var name_element = document.getElementById('name')
  var race_element = document.getElementById('race')
  var job_element = document.getElementById('job')
  var player = new Player(name_element.value, race_element.value, job_element.value)
  var msg = player.race+' '+player.job+' '+player.name+' enter the arena.'
  
  var player_element = document.getElementById('player')
  player_element.innerHTML += '<p>'+msg+'</p>'
  name_element.value = ''
  race_element.value = ''
  job_element.value = ''
}

function Player(name, race, job) {
  this.name = name
  this.race = race
  this.job = job
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="race" id="race">
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="job" id="job">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="spawnPlayer()" value="Spawn">
<div id="player">

</div>
```

Comment: localStorage?..

Comment: Cookies, session storage?

Comment: What do you mean by "temporarily"? Within the current session, or should the data be accessible after the user has closed the page/browser and then come back?